# Validate.js - error on regular type="text"

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am having a problem using validate.js

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

All the inputs work perfect such as `<input type="email" class="required" />`

my problem is,

I want to show the validation on normal 
`<input type="text" class="required" />` so if the user selects and leaves the input, 
the ***this field is required is shown***.

I have tried both `$("#confirm_add").validate();` and 
`$("#confirm_add").validate({`
`rules: {`
`user[first_name]: "required"`
`}`
`});`

the only way I can achieve this effect is including minlength="2" in the input, but I would prefer not to use that,

any help is well appreciated

Comment: a little out of contex, but you should use validationEngine, way better in many ways http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Comment: @gkaykck - thanks for that, looks good. unfortunantly I am required to use this plugin in the mean time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29), you need to quote field names with brackets in them.  If you have this html:

```
<input type="text" name="user[first_name]" />
```

You need this in your rules:

```
...
  'user[first_name]': {
      required: true
  }
...
```

As to the question of having it immediately show the validation, it just doesn't work that way by default, so you'd have to add code to handle that afterwards, using the [valid](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) method:

```
$('#firstname').blur(function(){
    $(this).valid();
});
```

See it all in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/NVZr8/

Note that if all you are doing is setting `required`, there's no reason to use the rules object, just set the `class="required"` in the input.

Comment: @KarlDoyle excellent, you should read this part of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for how to finish off the question.